# Meteor jQuery animate not working

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm trying to scroll a page when the template renders using this code:

```
Template.message.rendered = function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $('ul#message-list li:last').offset().top
     }, 600);
}
```

Nothing happens. The element definitely exists. Has anyone run into jQuery animate not working in meteor?

Comment: Does that element exist when the template first renders, or is it conditionally rendered via `#if`, `#each`, etc.?

Comment: Actually, it might not exist yet, but I tried with another elm that definitely does exist and no scrolling happens.

Comment: test your code in the console first is it really working? It probably should work. There is no reason for it if it exists at the time of execution

Comment: @CocoaNub have you found solution i stuck with same